In VSCode not able to jump out of the parentheses even after using Tabout extension
sum += a[i]
after typing 'i', pressing tab need to bring the cursor out of the brackets, but it first gives a tab space(4 spaces) and pressing tab once more brings the cursor out of the brackets.
here there is a keybinding conflict between "tab" and "tabout". I obviously cant change the tab keybinding which indents lines, and also I dont want to change the tabout keybinding. all I want is when inside brackets tabout needs to work instead of tab. what to do?

Normally using tab text make intend, just Use Arrow Keys ;-) ! otherwise it may conflict
